# Multiple subscript style

Tags: subscripts

I need to write some multi-lower index equations.
My goal is to get something like this:
[image: Goal]

Unfortunatelly, when I use normal "_" then I get this:
[image: Current]

Edit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Warsaw}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
P=\Big[ p_{ p_{1}}, p_{ p_{2}}, p_{ p_{3}},..., p_{ p_{ N_{ imp}}}\Big]
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How to change it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show the code?

Comment: What egreg asks for is a Minimum Working Example, starting with `\documentclass`.

Comment: `P = \Bigl[p_{p_{1}^{}}^{}, p_{p_{2}^{}}^{}, p_{p_{3}^{}}^{}, \dots, p_{p_{N_{imp}^{}}^{}}^{}\Bigr]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In these cases it's helpful to add empty superscripts that push down a little the subscripts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Warsaw}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
P=\Big[ p^{}_{p^{}_{1}}, p^{}_{p^{}_{2}}, p^{}_{p^{}_{3}},\dots,
 p^{}_{p^{}_{N_{\textnormal{imp}}}}\Big]
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that “imp” should be upright, not being a product of i times m times p, but a textual abbreviation.